# Generate canada postal code from given range in java

Tags: java, utility

I've been searching for a while but didn't find any solution. For example, if given ranges are like [A0A0A0 -A0P1M9] - It should give all possible valid Canadian postal codes for a given range. TIA.

example:
input From : A0A0A0
input To : A0A0A4
output : A0A0A0,A0A0A1,A0A0A2,A0A0A3,A0A0A4

Comment: If you want answers from non-Canadians as well, you should give us a reference describing the Canadian postal code system. And to conform to the rules of this site, you should describe what you have tried so far and where you're experiencing problems.

Comment: Sure. Canadian postal code is of 6 length where it is a combination of char and number. it's regex like  "^(?!.*[DFIOQU])[A-VXY][0-9][A-Z] ?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$"

Comment: Does e.g. "from A0A0A0 to A0A0B0" include A0A0A9? Or is it only A0A0A0 and A0A0B0?

Comment: yes, it includes. inclusive of from and to given.

Comment: ex: from A0A0A0 to A0A0B0"
output : A0A0A0,A0A0A1.....A0A0A9,A0A0B0

Answer (score 1):

I'd convert the possible String codes to consecutive numbers according to something like a mixed base-10 and base-26 system, multiplying the character's value by a position-dependent factor:

- char 0 by `10*26*10*26*10`
- char 1 by `26*10*26*10`
- char 2 by `10*26*10`
- char 3 by `26*10`
- char 4 by `10`
- char 5 by `1`

Typically, I'd represent A..Z as 0..25, only (to avoid the gap at the missing W and Z character in the first place) I'd adjust the mapping at that position.

Then, I'd produce all numbers in between the two converted limits, and convert them back with the reverse scheme.

Be aware that in the worst case A0A0A0..Y9Z9Z9 you'll get 16 million strings.